# Making a certain tree style the default for forest

Tags: forest

We are putting together latex classes for books. We want to make a certain tree style the default for `forest`. With the example below one has to define the style (sn edges) in every tree. Is there a way to get rid of this specification and make it the default?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges
[S
  [NP [er\\he] ]
  [NP
    [Det [das\\the] ]
    [N [Buch\\book] ] 
  ]
  [NP
    [Det [der\\the] ]
    [N [Frau\\woman] ] 
  ]
  [V [gibt\\gives] ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if the question is unsolved Stefan, but this code for instance is applied to all forest environments:

```
\forestset{.style={for tree={l=1em, l sep=1em, s sep=1em}}}
```

In essence, just drop the style name :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also say `\forestset{.style={sn edges}}`

Comment: I had no idea this is possible, and I'm the author of `forest` :-)  However, to make the issue clearer, the next version will implement key `default preamble`. Usage just as above: `\forestset{default preamble/.style={sn edges}}}`

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Has this feature been added yet?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović, I'm also interested in whether this feature has been added yet. I don't see it in the July 15 documentation.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović, Are you indicating in your example that the `sn edges` style will be pre-loaded by `forest` so that the code for the style doesn't have be copied into the preamble? I like the flexibility and simple syntax of `forest`, and it's great for compact trees, but I hesitate to recommend it to my linguistics students because it doesn't work "out of the box" the way `tikz-qtree` does. If I could tell them to just use `\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}` where the `linguistics` option would load `sn edges` and `nice empty nodes` for every tree, that would be great.

Comment: The feature will be added in v1.1. This summer, promise! ;-)  Thanks for the `\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}` idea, I like it!

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Have you thought about having something like `\useforestlibrary{linguistics}`? Then people could create libraries as they can for TikZ which grouped related styles etc. together. Otherwise, as soon as you have a `linguistics` option, somebody (like me) will be asking for a `logic` option and then somebody else will be using a completely different kind of proof tree and will want `otherlogic`... and how can you say no to `decisiontheory` and `probability` when you've said yes to `linguistics`, `logic` and `otherlogic`?

Comment: Yess, this is implemented in the upcoming version. `\usepackage{forest}\useforestlibrary{linguistics}` loads the base package plus linguistics-related stuff, and `\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}` additionally makes linguistic style the default. And I will be extremely glad to include `logic` and co!

Comment: Progress report: it took a long time and lots of work, but I'm finally in the testing phase. TeX.SE is a great help here, as I'm checking for discrepancies between v1.0.x and v1.1 using the code posted on this site!

Comment: I finally know why this method worked. I wrote `\pgfkeys{/forest/.is family}` and then used `\pgfkeys{/forest, ...}` at the end of `for X` propagators. All perfectly legal at first sight, but when `/forest` is redefined, which is precisely what `.style/{...}` does, then the redefinition is called not just once, but a million times!